# Why do git and mercurial reports conflicts in a file when the same change is made on both sides?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

For instance, if I have a file that contains the text ABC, and then I make a branch and change it to ABCD, but then go back to the original branch and also change it to ABCD, then I merge the branches together, there is a conflict! But the files are identical; why do I need to resolve a nonexistent conflict?

Comment: Git shouldn't detect this as a conflict. I've also just tried it and there was no conflict. Can you show how the unmerged conflicting file looks?

Comment: Huh, I already merged my example of this... guess I'll have to wait for it to happen again!

Comment: Dis you accidentally add an extra character in one file and not the other? A carriage return for example?

Comment: You should be able to repeat the identical merge and reproduce the same effect

Comment: @Mokubai I was thinking the same thing.